# Which class run() method invoked first? and Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have tried the following code using threading concept, In this code, I have declare two run methods in two different class. and I have invoked those method from my main method.
 Actually What I want to know is, Which run() method is invoked first?
I got different output for same code, when I'm running again and again.

My Code:

```
class parent
{
    public synchronized void display1()
    {
        System.out.println("Dispaly_1 is invoked");
    }
    public synchronized void display2()
    {
        System.out.println("Dispaly_2 is invoked");
    }
}
class abc extends Thread{
    parent p;
    public abc(parent p){
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("abc start...");     
        p.display1();
    }
}
class xyz extends Thread{
    parent p;
    public xyz(parent p){
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("xyz start...");     
        p.display2();
    }
}

public class ThreadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        parent p=new parent();
        abc ob=new abc(p);
        xyz ob1=new xyz(p);
        ob.start();
        ob1.start();

    }

}
```

Outputs:
1st time

```
abc start...
xyz start...
Dispaly_2 is invoked
Dispaly_1 is invoked
```

2nd time

```
xyz start...
Dispaly_2 is invoked
abc start...
Dispaly_1 is invoked
```

3rd time

```
abc start...
Dispaly_1 is invoked
xyz start...
Dispaly_2 is invoked
```

I have confused with this output, Anyone Can explain this result of the code.
Your help will appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Threads run asynchronously and their exact ordering with respect to each other is unpredictable.  That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 5):

> Which class run() method invoked first?

Either.

> and Why?

It's indeterminate. Up to the thread scheduler.

If you want sequential execution, don't use threads.

Answer (score 1):

It's all depends on the scheduler,A thread can be managed independently by Scheduler.even if you start your abc thread first, xyz may get executed first by scheduler or vice versa.

First started thread will not execute first all the time.

Hope my answer gives some clarity on scheduler.